# How to efficiently move in Unity2D?

Tags: 2d, unity

If i want to use Physics in Unity2D what should be the most efficient way to move the object without interfering physics?

```
 1. Transform.position
 2. Rigidbody.Velocity
 3. Rigidbody.addForce
 4. Transform.translate
 5. Rigidbody.movePosition
```

Seems like there are a lot of ways and each way has a special purpose for when it should be used and when not. I just don't know that.

Comment: You may find the answers to this question useful, as it covers the same ground (not specific to 2D, but all the same considerations apply): [When should I use velocity versus addForce when dealing with player objects?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113178/when-should-i-use-velocity-versus-addforce-when-dealing-with-player-objects)

Comment: Also related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118711/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-translate-and-rigidbody-velocity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the velocity will interfere with your physics if you're not sure of what you're doing. Ideally, you'd move things around by [adding forces](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/addforce?playlist=17120). Using [`Rigidbody2D.AddForce`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) is the least complicated way to move objects that have a RigidBody.

Comment: But when you constantly add force your object's speed goes on increasing how to maintain a constant speed?

Comment: Only add force until the speed is what you want, then stop adding force.

Comment: It means we can't move at a constant velocity from rest, we'll have to accelerate to that velocity?

Comment: Yes, that's how physics works. There's no instantaneous changes in velocity. If you want to violate that, then you should change the velocity instead. But you'll need to account for any changes in the velocity the physics system makes, like drag, bouncing off other objects or walls, etc. You can also set a maximum velocity and have a very high acceleration.

Comment: Setting Very High Acceleration seems a nice trick.

Comment: -1 adding to force does interfere with physics

Comment: @evorlor, I guess you'd have to define 'interfere'. I'd say adding forces is supplying the physics system with inputs, not interfering. Thanks for commenting about your reason.